# UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to path denied

Tags: c#, xmldocument, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

When attempting to load an xml document for parsing, I continuously get the following error:

```
    An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Private.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
    Access to the path 'C:\Users\Delan\Code\Questions.xml' is denied.
```

This is a file, not a directory. The file is not read-only. It has full system access. I am running VS Code in administrator mode. I have moved the file around into several other directories, even creating new ones. I cannot see what is wrong with my code to be getting this error. After hours of searching, it seems the above solutions have worked for others, but they are not working for me.
Any help or nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Code I have saved currently:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string path = @"C:\\Users\\Delan\\Code\\Questions.xml";
    doc.Load(path); // This is what causes the error
```

Comment: If you use `@""` for a string, you don't need to escape your back slashes

Comment: I didnt originally have them escaped. I ended up escaping them to see if that was somehow the issue and just never changed it back

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing your Administrator but are you sure your application runs as admin or does it use another group/user?

Comment: It does. It default runs as user but ive been running it as admin for this

Comment: Let me rephrase that, are you sure your developed application is running as admin? In the first question you only mentioned you run visual studio code as admin.

Comment: Yes. The application itself runs under admin privilege. Not just visual studio